# iOS - Search View Controller glitch

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller

[image]
[image]

I can only assume the effect above is happening because Search Display Controllers are normally designed to work with just a navigation bar above them. As you can see, in this design there is a toolbar containing a segmented control underneath the navigation bar.

This is creating quite a mess as can be seen in screenshot two. Is there any way to just disable the Search Display Controller position animating effect or offset it differently in any way?

The end goal was simply to have 3 different lists in 3 different views and have each one filterable. Any ideas how to get around this view glitch?